# Combine various sub routines into one sub routine (IDA Pro)

Tags: ida, binary-analysis

Currently I am analyzing a .so file and there is a function which is supposed to be large (high number of nodes and edges). However, IDA Pro identified it as a small function, with various parts of the code being treated as individual sub routines and some of them have attributes of "no return".

I tried to use append_func_tail to combine the sub routines together but the function returns false.

I am trying to do these

- Combine the various sub routines together into one main sub routine
- Calculate the cyclomatic complexity value of this big sub routine

Is there a way to do the above?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE! Can you provide an ida database of binary containing the function in question?

Comment: If these function fragments are placed sequentially, manual fix is possible. Delete all the functions that IDA created instead of function fragments (AFAIR, Edit-->Functions-->Delete function). Select all the instructions that should be in the large function, and press P. This should create a large function from the selected instructions.

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot share the database because the file is proprietary and I am not allowed to share it. I see some suggestions below to try out, will try them.

Comment: I would like to add that the functions are not located sequentially but "scattered" throughout

Answer (score 1):

If IDA has erroneously marked functions as "noreturn", you can manually edit this with `Alt-P`. "Does not return" is a checkmark that you can select. Once you've removed this attribute, IDA should properly disassemble the code following the function call -- though you may need to delete functions (as the comment said) if IDA is using obsolete information about the function boundaries.

Comment: Rerunning IDA's autoanalysis (Options->General->Analysis->Reanalyze program) will fix/adjust most of the incorrectly analyzed functions. That's worth trying before manually deleting functions.

Comment: hey folks! Thanks for the reply, will try the suggestions.

Comment: Hi folks, I unchecked the "no return" attribute, deleted the sub routines and ran analysis again but IDA Pro just identify those sub routines as individual sub routines as per its original analysis.

I was not able to manually highlight the code portions and indicate them as one big function as they were not located sequentially.

Anything else I can try?